# How to open a file that contains Chinese characters, in java IO?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class JavaIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream("F:\Java的提高学习\from.txt");
        }  
        catch(Exception e ){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

`fis = new FileInputStream("F:\Java的提高学习\from.txt")` causes an error due to the Chinese characters in the path name of the file. Please help me deal with this problem.

Comment: What kind of error? Saying "there's an error" is about as helpful as saying "something went wrong".

Comment: The error is "invalid escape sequence".

Comment: Use fis = new FileInputStream("F:\\Java的提高学习\\from.txt"); instead, as Java tries to interpret \J and \f as escape sequence. You have to escape all backslashes in Java Strings.

Comment: final byte[] bytes = fileName.getBytes("Shift_JIS");                new String(bytes,"ISO8859_1"); - use this string as path

Answer (score 5):

It's not because of the Chinese characters.

In a Java string, `\n` represents a newline. `\t` represents a tab. `\"` represents a quote mark. `\\` represents a single `\`. There are a few more that are less commonly used. These sets of "`\` then another character" are called escape sequences.

`\J` is an invalid escape sequence. `\f` is a valid escape sequence but it's not what you want.

To put an actual backslash in a string, you need to use the `\\` escape sequence instead. Like this:

```
fis = new FileInputStream("F:\\Java的提高学习\\from.txt");
```